# Keydown event: how to capture down and up key rows?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm-light

I am trying to capture the down and up keys (the direction rows) but when I press this keys, it is not raised the event keydown.

However, if I press any other key, the event is raised. For example numlock is catched. The row keys are special keys?

I am using MVVMLight to convert the events to command, and pass the KeyEventArgs.

Thanks.

EDIT: add some code

Well. really I have a comboBox, and is editable, so I can write text inside the comboBox. How the search option is enabled, while I am writing, the selecition is changed.

So the selection can change for many reasons: I write and the comboBox change the selection because of the search option, I can change the selection with the mouse and I can change the selection with the arrow keys.

I would like to know which is the reason of the selection change. So I need to know when in my comboBox I press down or up arrow keys.

I have this code:

AXML

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Type" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="0,16,0,0" Name="cmbType" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="238"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Types}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=TypesIndex}" IsEditable="True"
            Text="{Binding TypesText}">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TypesPreviewKeyDownCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>    
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TypesSelectionChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cmbTypes, Path=SelectedItems}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>    
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ComboBox>
```

In my viewModel:

```
private RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> _typesPreviewKeyDownCommand = null;
        public RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> typesPreviewKeyDownCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_typesPreviewKeyDownCommand == null)
                {
                    _typesPreviewKeyDownCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(typesPreviewKeyDownCommand);
                }
                return _typesPreviewKeyDownCommand;
            }
        }





private void typesPreviewKeyDownCommand(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                //my code
            }
            else
            {
                //more code
            }
        }
```

Comment: Page down/page up or down arrow/up arrow?

Comment: The keys are the arrow keys, the keys between the right ctrl and numeric pad (in most of the keyboards).

Comment: Can you please add some code to your question so we can see how you're hooking things up.

Comment: Probably keys are handled in some other place because of you use bubbled event. Use `PreviewKeyDown`, it is tunneled one

Comment: I am using PreviewKeyDown. The problem is that I can capture all keys except arrow keys.

Comment: First off, you have the wrong event args in your command handlers. You have KeyEventArgs, but need PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if relevant anymore, but here's an article on CodeProject which discusses a very similar issue/behaviour
[Up/Down behavior on a DatePicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663143/Quick-intro-to-DatePicker-tricks-and-MVVM-thoughts)

It's very simple to handle in the Code Behind like the article suggests, but if you want to do it MVVM style, you need to go with the `i:Interaction` or `InputBindings`. 
I prefer the Interaction, since coupled with mvvm-light it seems to work better for me, while with the `InputBindings` I've found that up/down keys didn't work, while having a modifier like ALT would work.

As the comments said, it's probably being handled somewhere on the way before it gets to you. (this is why you'd like to use the `PreviewKeyDown` and not `KeyDown`).