# Reading Keyboard Input from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

i am using the MVVM pattern with WPF and Prism (unity). I have a tool which is reading a barcode scanned by a user and depending on what kind of barcode is scanned the tool is doing some stuff. Right now i have a textbox which is binded to a property. I would like to fill my property in the viewmodel with the content of the scanned barcode without using a textbox or similar. I would like to fill the property directly. Is there a way to do this? Or maybe someone have an idea how i could solve that problem?

kind regards

Comment: not sure what you're asking really ... you mean, not manually, or not in a textbox? or something else?

Comment: Yea correctly. I mean when i scan a barcode (it's the same like a usual keyboard input), i want to save the content of the barcode directly to a property and not to a textbox which is binded to a property

Comment: hmmm ... you might need to have an event listener, and do it from there. I haven't worked with scanners, so couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: a scanner is actually the same as a keyboard. just usual keyboard input is coming from it

Comment: If the binding mode is TwoWay, any text changes should end up right in the ViewModel property. (ie. add Mode=TwoWay to the binding)

Comment: i think he wants to avoid the textbox, and go straight to the model, without the need for the textbox binding

Comment: right noctis. Thats what i need.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, what you'll want to do is handle the keydown event.

Have a read here: [code project scanner reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296533/Using-a-bar-code-scanner-in-NET) . He did what you want, and show what / where to handle :)

**Edit:**
I've answered another key events question that might be relevant. Feel free to have a look [at my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217245/1698987) , it discusses `i:interaction` and `InputBindings` , and points in return to another article about handling key events: [up/down on datepicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663143/Quick-intro-to-DatePicker-tricks-and-MVVM-thoughts), and discusses the code behind / mvvm approaches.

Hope you'll find them useful.

Comment: Thank you Noctis. I'll have a look at it and i also need to find out how to convert his logic to mvvm :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure I'm getting it in the right way, but you can catch all keyboard input with EventManager.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window),
     Keyboard.KeyUpEvent,new KeyEventHandler(keyUp), true);


private void keyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if(e.Key == Key.OemComma)
             MessageBox.Show("Gotcha");
}
```

Another option is to create a read only textbox, but it's more or less same as you have now.

Comment: not sure about what he wants, but the mvvm comment might mean he doesn't want code behind ...

Comment: You can do it on app domain level or you can extract it into an attached property.