# C# - How to handle XAML Keyboard in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Untill now, I'm using the .xaml.cs to handle the inputs.

Here is my xaml head code :

```
<Window x:Class="My_Windows_App.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:My_Windows_App.ViewModel"
Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="900"
Keyboard.KeyDown="keyDownEventHandler" Keyboard.KeyUp="keyUpEventHandler">
```

And here is a part of the MainWindow.xaml.cs code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool pushToTalk;

        public void keyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
                pushToTalk = true;
        }

        public void keyUpEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
                pushToTalk = false;
        }
}
```

How can I implent the same thing in MVVM ?
Because as far as I understand, we can not bind a method, only properties, right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Input handling is a View concern, not a ViewModel concern, why would you want to move that to the ViewModel?

instead, delegate the application / business logic to the ViewModel, while keeping the Keyboard Input handling in the View:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MyViewModel ViewModel;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    }


    public void keyDownEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
            ViewModel.PushToTalk = true;
    }

    public void keyUpEventHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
            ViewModel.PushToTalk = false;
    }
}
```

Notice how I moved the `PushToTalk` property to the ViewModel, because that is really part of the application logic and not the UI, while keeping Keyboard events at the View level. This does not break MVVM because you're not mixing UI and application logic, you're just placing things where they really belong.

Comment: While this might work, MVVM is not about Events. A "purist" would call the cops on you :p

Comment: @Tico Wrong. MVVM is about not putting the business logic and UI together, not about senseless arbitrary restrictions about what can be used and what not. My solution complies with MVVM by having the View take care of it's concerns while keeping the business logic in the ViewModel.

Comment: Ok, I believe. But doesn't it conflicts with the `Command` pattern? I'm not a purist. But separation of Ui/Logic can be achieved with others architectures as well

Comment: It does conflict with `Command` pattern, but there does seem like no way to  put a command on the Window itself. As far as I can tell, @Noctis's answer doesn't work because Interaction.Triggers can not be stuck on the window.  There is also no EventTrigger for KeyDown/KeyUp so no go in that direction.

Answer (score 22):

Seems you got your answer, but here's another take on a solution.
You can tackle the keyboard events with `i:interaction` and `InputBindings`. Some examples using a `DatePicker` with interaction would be:

```
<DatePicker Name="fancy_name_here" SelectedDate="{Binding your_date_property_here}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">               
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=TestMeCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DatePicker>
```

(Do note that you'll need the next line in your window definitions for the `i:Interaction` to work:)

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

and for the input binding:

```
<DatePicker Name="fancy_name_here"  SelectedDate="{Binding your_date_property_here}">
  <DatePicker.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Modifiers="Shift" Command="{Binding your_command_name}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{Binding TestMeCommand}" />       
    <KeyBinding Key="Up" Command="{Binding TestMeCommand}" />        
  </DatePicker.InputBindings>
</DatePicker>
```

Feel free to have a look [at my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19217245/1698987) , it discusses `i:interaction` and `InputBindings` , and points in return to another article about handling key events: [up/down on datepicker](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663143/Quick-intro-to-DatePicker-tricks-and-MVVM-thoughts), and discusses the code behind / mvvm approaches.

Hope you'll find them useful.

Comment: +1. I was about to post this. There's no need to use a "Toolkit" and works great.

Comment: While this approach is OK, I don't see how you deal with `OnKeyUp` here, in order to toggle the `PushToTalk` property to false, as the OP is doing.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for handling the "Enter" key in a TextBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UploadNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding 
      Key="Enter" 
      Command="{Binding FindUploadCommand}" 
      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```